# c# Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

AoA,  Hello
i am writing an application for financial solution. in short i ve to get out print of report that is generated. Crystal report is what i want to use.... 
my problem is that i just want to preview report and allow to insert any change that user want to make. Or easily we can say want to allow edit entries.

is there any method to preview?.... Note that i am newbie ..... so apology if i am unable to deliver correct question. Hope you understand and will help me.
take care.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what type of project you are working on (ASP? Winforms?)... but I suspect the answer may be similar in all cases.

While a preview control is available in Crystal Reports (at least version XI, for WinForms based solutions), I am 95% certain that the preview is non-editable. I believe that if you wanted to change fields within the report you would need to "re-run" the report processing before you could get an updated preview.

Comment: make it a 100%. You have to rerun your report indeed